# How can I swallow an exception that is thrown inside a catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Below is some of my error logging code. When an exception happens inside my app, I log it to a database.  If that database is down or when there's some other problem, I try to log it in an event viewer.

What happens if that event viewer write fails for some reason, too? How do I *give up* or swallow this new exception?

```
void SaveLog(string accountId, Exception ex, Category category, Priority priority)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(…))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // exception while logging!   
        using (var eventLog = new EventLog { Source = "tis" })
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry(
                exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + 
                exception.StackTrace,
                EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing special about a catch block. *How would you do it outside of a catch block?* Do it the same way inside the catch block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
try {
    // ...
}
catch (Exception exception) {
    try {
        // Attempt to write to event log.
    }
    catch {
    }
}
```